Loop over object of dictionaris in power automate
I have an object of dictionary objects (key:{value})
I want to dynamically loop over the keys of that object and access its properties inside a power automate flow. I am unable to find the possible expression or actions to do that.
here is my current object example:
{
    "Prop1": {
      "value": "test",
      "displayName": "test",
      "fieldType": "string",
      "text": "test"
    },
    "Prop2": {
      "value": "temp",
      "displayName": "temp",
      "fieldType": "string",
      "text": "temp"
    }
}


You have a couple of options, both of which can be found in this answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79054768/logic-app-power-automate-extract-checklist-items-from-a-task-from-a-planner-p/79060350#79060350
